# Set overflow to hidden on body by click on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to write a snippet of code, to set the body tag on `overflow: hidden`,  when someone opens the menu (which is a fullscreen menu). It should also set it back to `auto`, when the user clicks on close. The problem that I have is, that it sets it to hidden, but don't reset it to auto, when the menu is closed. What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript

```
function() {
  $('.menu-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  $('.menu-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
    <a href="#" class="menu-icon w-inline-block w-clearfix">
        <div class="menu-icon__line left"></div>
        <div class="menu-icon__line"></div>
        <div class="menu-icon__line right"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put it in the form of a jsFiddle or code snippet.

Comment: how do the event handlers "know" which one you want? they both get triggered each time

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @A.Meshu - how does that help with css overflow property?

Comment: @JaromandaX it dosen't - but it might lead the OP in building the function to toggle between the two modes. Although your answer is better (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ONE and only ONE click handler, which toggles the overflow attribute

as follows

```js
(function() {
  $('.menu-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').css('overflow', $('body').css('overflow') == 'hidden' ? 'auto' : 'hidden');
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-button w-nav-button">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</div>
```

```
    $('body').css('overflow', $('body').css('overflow') == 'hidden' ? 'auto' : 'hidden');
```

could also be written

```
    $('body').css('overflow', $('body').css('overflow') == '' ? 'hidden' : '');
```

since "auto" is the "default" value for overflow

however, depending on the initial state of overflow, that may not work exactly right ... i.e. if initial state is `hidden` by a style sheet ... so in that case you'd invert the logic

```
$('body').css('overflow', $('body').css('overflow') == '' ? 'auto' : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow-hidden');
});
```

CSS

```
.overflow-hidden {overflow: hidden}
```

Replace `.css()` with `.toggleClass()`